# Given MySQL varchar value ages "4 to 8", or "30+", how can I SELECT for record if I am looking for age of say "5"

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, numbers

I have to make a website that works with a MySQL data set. One of the table values is AgeRange where the values are varchar and can be "1 to 2", "3 - 4", "4 - 8"..."30+" and I want, given any number say 5, be able to find the corresponding row based on where 5 would fit in. In this case it would be "4-8". My problem is that that is a string and I'm not sure how to parse out 4 and 8 and use >= and <= to find if 5 fits in, or how do I parse out the 30 from "30+" and find that 5<=30?

I tried something like this below, thinking I could cover the case where the table value is "30+", but it ends up not working for "1-2", "3-4" etc. And this is not to mention using a value for comparison for unlisted ages between a range like 5.

```
SELECT *
FROM personTable
WHERE ageRange LIKE ("% 2") XOR ageRange LIKE ("2 %") XOR ageRange LIKE ("2%")
```

I'm really stuck and need your help, thank you.

**EDIT:**
Picture of my db: https://gyazo.com/49b939b53278ab2432c6bc56aab000ee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way: Store range in two columns (range_start, range_end)

---

For format `a-b` you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE 5 BETWEEN substring_index(`column`,'-',1)
    AND substring_index(substring_index(`column`,'-',-1),'-',1);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/BLABR97537)**

**EDIT:**

Handling`+`:

```
SELECT *
FROM personTable
WHERE 31 BETWEEN substring_index(ageRange,'-',1) AND
  CASE WHEN RIGHT(substring_index(substring_index(ageRange,'-',-1),'-',1),1)='+' 
       THEN 999
       ELSE substring_index(substring_index(ageRange,'-',-1),'-',1)
  END
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/VNTWQ68960)**

Comment: Appreciate it, I'll try it out and let you know. But that wouldn't work for `a+` case?

Comment: Just add CASE to handle it

Comment: `a-b` format doesn't seem to fully work for my table. I might be misinterpreting what I'm supposed to put for column. So the ageRange is but one of multiple columns. And I'm going to run `SELECT * FROM entire TABLE ...` and I substitute `column` with `ageRange`?

It only works for initial value of a range like 1 in "1 to 2", or 3 in "3-4". If I put 1 as `WHERE 1 BETWEEN...` I'll get back all the records with the ageRange value of `1 to 2` but if I put 2 I get back nothing. Same with 5 for records with '4 to 8'.

Comment: Yeah sorry dude I don't what to say. It's not working for my table. Starting range number works when I put it in but not end ranges or inbetween umbers. The `a+` case works fine.

https://gyazo.com/49b939b53278ab2432c6bc56aab000ee

Here's an image of my db if that helps. The code works for your Rexhester demo but not my db for some reason.

Comment: Ah i see the problem, it is my fault. My db used "to" for the age range, and I mistakenly put "-" here. Thanks for the solution.